# How to create a POST request in REST to accept a JSON input?

Tags: json, spring, rest, post, jackson

I am trying to learn RESTful web services. And am creating a simple set of web services. Got stuck when I started working on POST.

I want to pass JSON input to a POST method. This is what I did in the code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/x-www-form-urlencoded", produces="text/plain")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public @ResponseBody String createChangeRequest(MyCls mycls) {
    return "YAHOOOO!!"; 
}
```

I included Jackson in my POM.xml.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

MyCls is a simple class with a few getters and setters.

I am calling the above POST service from chrome's simple REST client.

```
URL: http://localhost:8080/MYWS/cls/create
Data: {<valid-json which corresponds to each variable in the MyCls pojo}
```

I see the below response:

```
415 Unsupported Media Type
The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.
```

I tried adding header as "application/json" in the POST request in the REST client - but that did not help.

Can someone let me know what I am missing here? How can I automatically map my input JSON to the MyCls pojo? Am I missing any configuration here?

Edit:
MyCls.java

```
public class MyCls{
   private String name;
   private String email;
   private String address;
       public String getName() {
    return name;
   }
   public void setName(String name) {
    name= name;
   }
       ---similar getter and setter for email, address--
}
```

json from chrome Simple REST Client:

```
{"name":"abc", "email":"de@test","address":"my address"}
```

Edit:
Changed my controller method to the following, but still see the same error:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json", produces="text/plain")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
 public @ResponseBody String createChangeRequest(@RequestBody MyCls mycls) {
  return "YAHOOOO!!"; 
 }
```

Comment: Could you show `MyCls`?

Comment: @Bart - edited the question with MyCls.java and the JSON from the client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your client is sending `application/json` as its content type, then a handler mapped to

```
consumes="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

will not be able to handle it. The actual `Content-type` doesn't match the expected.

If you are expecting `application/json`, you should instead have

```
consumes="application/json"
```

Also, declaring

```
public @ResponseBody String createChangeRequest(MyCls mycls) {
```

is (in default environment) equivalent to

```
public @ResponseBody String createChangeRequest(@ModelAttribute MyCls mycls) {
```

This means the `MyCls` object is created from request parameters, not from JSON body. Instead, you should have

```
public @ResponseBody String createChangeRequest(@RequestBody MyCls mycls) {
```

so that Spring deserializes your JSON to an object of type `MyCls`.

Comment: Made both the changes you suggested, but I still see the same issue. Is there any other configuration that I am missing?

Comment: It looks like a jackson message mapper is needed. Is that understanding correct?

Comment: @user If Jackson libs are on the class path, your MVC config should register it by default.

Comment: changed my method based on your suggestions above, but I still see the same issue. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: @user Are you sure your client is sending application/json?

Comment: it turned out that the Header was not set in the POST request from the client. After setting the Header value in client to "application/json", I was able to see the JSON being mapped to my POJO. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.